# wysiwyg editor - with code

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am looking to use wordpress editor via the front end.

i have looked at the plugin wordpress front end editor. But it doesn't seem to use the wordpress tinymce, i want to mimic the one that is used in the backend admin section in the front end.

Is this even possible i have been googling all sorts off solutions for hours, i think the wp_tiny_mce(); has depreciated with the new version.

Can some please help????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some quick Googling I dug up the following [link](http://wpmu.org/8-wordpress-plugins-that-enable-posting-and-editing-from-the-front-end/) which appears to give a few possible plugin options.